# Calling a global string variable from Fortran in C causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fortran, mixed-programming

I'm trying to call a global string variable which is defined in a Fortran subroutine, in C. the C code is `Cfile.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
        int length;
        char* string;
} fstring;

extern fstring stringf_;
void fortfunc_();

int main() {
        fstring stringC = stringf_;
        stringC.string[stringC.length-1] = '\0';
        printf("%s \n",stringC.string);
        return 0;
}
```

and FORTRAN code is `Ffile.f`:

```
subroutine fortfunc()
  
        character*30 string
        common/stringF/ string
        string = 'this is a string in FROTRAN77'

return
end
```

it compiles with:

```
gcc -c Cfile.c
gfortran -c -std=legacy Ffile.f
gfortran -c file.out -std=legacy Cfile.o Ffile.o
```

but when running I get the segmentation fault. I do not understand when I'm violating the memory boundaries though.

My operating system is:

> Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 23 15:48:01 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

and my compilers are:

> GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0
>
> gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0

I would appreciate if you could help me know where is my mistake and how I can solve it? other solutions to define a global variable in Fortran and then calling it in C are also welcomed.

Comment: verify that `stringC.length` is valid (>0) before using it as index.

Comment: @Aganju good point. I had already figured out that the returns 0 and that causes the segfault. but the questions remains then how can I pass a string from FORTRAN to C. you see more examples [here](https://github.com/Foadsf/Cmathtuts/tree/dev/A_fortran).

Comment: Even better learn how to spell Fortran and search for "pass a string from Fortran to C"

Comment: Hold on a second, generally speaking, local variables, unless static in C, don't have any scope outside of the function... In that sense, it would be a good idea to test the variable in the Fortran module, in a test module I think. See if you can print it there before trying to get it from the C function. Many thanks for the update!

Comment: Changing the code to "typedef struct { char string[ 30 ]; } fstring;" and "stringC.string[ 29 ] = '\0';" works on my computer (<-- I think the common block contains raw characters rather than the pointer to them)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments I got here and on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/fortran/comments/a1ywwm/calling_a_global_string_variable_from_fortran_in/), I now have a code which works. The C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char s[30];
} fstring;

extern fstring stringf_;

int main() {
    fstring stringc = stringf_;
    stringc.s[29] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",stringc.s);
    return 0;
}
```

and FORTRAN code:

```
        BLOCK DATA

                CHARACTER*30 S
                COMMON /STRINGF/ S
                DATA S /'this is a string in FROTRAN77'/

        end
```

The segfault was happening because the passed `stringC.length` value is zero. It means unlike the example I was following [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html) when calling a string from the FORTRAN side it does not pass the length as an integer!