# minimum modification to make a visual studio FORTRAN-C mixed code gfortran-gcc compatible

Tags: c, fortran, mixed-programming

I'm trying to modify [this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa293328(v%3Dvs.60)) ([gist as back up](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/f887f03a4cbf04921e98d7ccfc0e74b1)) to become gfortran-gcc compatible.

- I removed the `[VALUE]` tags
- used `POINTER` with `-fcray-pointer` flag for gfortran, instead of the `[REFERENCE]` tag
- removed the `__stdcall` , because tried the `#define __stdcall __attribute__((stdcall))` which caused `warning: ‘stdcall’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]`
  now this is what I have:

C code `CMAIN.C`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int FACT_(int n);
extern void PYTHAGORAS_(float a, float b, float *c);

main()
{
    float c;
    printf("Factorial of 7 is: %d\n", FACT_(7));
    PYTHAGORAS_(30, 40, &c);
    printf("Hypotenuse if sides 30, 40 is: %f\n", c);
}
```

the FORTRAN code `FORSUBS.FOR`:

```
  INTEGER*4 FUNCTION Fact (n)
  INTEGER*4 n 
  INTEGER*4 i, amt
  amt = 1
  DO i = 1, n
    amt = amt * i
  END DO
  Fact = amt
  END

  SUBROUTINE Pythagoras (a, b, cp)
  REAL*4 a
  REAL*4 b
  POINTER (cp, c)
  REAL*4 c
  c = SQRT (a * a + b * b)
  END
```

the `Makefile`:

```
all:
    gfortran -c FORSUBS.FOR -fcray-pointer
    gcc -c CMAIN.C
    gfortran -o result.out FORSUBS.o CMAIN.o  
    rm -rf *.o

clean :
    rm -rf *.out *~ *.bak *.o
```

However I still get the error:

> CMAIN.o: In function `main':
>
> CMAIN.C:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `FACT_(int)'
>
> CMAIN.C:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `PYTHAGORAS_(float, float, float*)'

I would appreciate if you could help me know:

- What is the issue and how can I resolve it?
- what is the best method to modify the original code to become gcc-gfortran compatible with minimum change.

**P.S.1.** also shared on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/fortran/comments/a2imhz/minimum_modification_to_make_a_visual_studio/).
**P.S.2.** operating system and compiler specifications are same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53567166/calling-a-global-string-variable-from-fortran-in-c-causes-segmentation-fault).

Comment: I really don't see any reason for the Cray pointers here.

Comment: @VladimirF any better method to pass a pointer from the C side?

Comment: You just need to pass the variable by referrence, not to pass a pointer. That is the default Fortran way and it is shown in any tutorial about old Fortran and C.

Comment: When I compile your `fortran`, and use `nm` on the `.o`, the symbols I get are: `fact_` and `pythagoras_` vs what you've declared in your `.c` file (i.e. they are _lower_ case vs. the _upper_ case you use in your `.c` file)

Comment: The name mangling is compiler specific. That's why we have [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding] in this century. There are tons of similar question here.

Comment: @VladimirF I'm using `gfortran` just as OP is. And, he can repeat the same test to see what should be specified.

Comment: @CraigEstey no idea what "use nm on the .o, the symbols" means, would you please elaborate? I just copy and pasted the error in my Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: @VladimirF I'm aware of the iso c binding. but I'm collecting all the available examples for FORTRAN 77-90 and C mixed programmings for my repository [here](https://github.com/Foadsf/Cmathtuts/tree/dev).

Comment: You wil find loads of older examples under that tag as well. Really, your code in the question is very basic and these technieques were discussed here many times.

Comment: @VladimirF would you mind providing link to a similar example?

Comment: BTW if you are willing ro use such a non-standard thing as Cray pointers, you could well use iso-c-binding as an extension to older Fortran as well. It cerrainly has better future in porrability.

Comment: The tag is full of such examples, but you can just also just read my answer when I took the time to write it..

Comment: @VladimirF I had no idea that `Cray pointers` are non-standard. I just googled fortran pointer and this was what I found. I write C but my knowledge of FORTRAN is still very primitive. what is the standard solution then?

Comment: To pass by reference as I wrote at least twice. Just remove the unneeded `[REFERENCE]`. You should be more worried about the pass by value.

Comment: @Foad, it is very clear that your knowledge of Fortran is still very primitive as the name of the language is Fortran.  It's been Fortran for 3 decades or so.

Comment: You have to remove `rm -rf *.o` from your `all:` target to retain your `.o` files. Doing `nm FORSUBS.o CMAIN.o` will output the symbol tables of each `.o`. `FORSUBS.o` will have `T` [text] symbols and `CMAIN.o` will show `U` type symbols. These should matchup.

Comment: It's not good to count on the legacy non-standard integer*4 from before the C era working with C. Better to use the C interoperable types.  VALUE in Windows Fortran (at least in a well-known implementation, not necessarily in gfortran) is not the same as iso_c_binding value attribute. In that case, the former would still match C pass by reference; it simply would isolate caller from any attempt by the callee to return data to caller..

Comment: @evets please correct me if I'm wrong but the versions prior to 95 including 66, 77 and 90 are spelled with capital letters. aren't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to my top comments, Fortran passes by reference, so you have to modify the `.c` and the `.for` files.

The code below works. There may be a simpler way to declare things, but this should [at least] get you further along. *Caveat*: I haven't done much fortran since Fortran IV days, so I'm a bit rusty. I'd defer to Vladimir's `VALUE` solution as a better way to go.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if 0
extern int fact_(int n);
extern void pythagoras_(float a, float b, float *c);
#else
extern int fact_(int *n);
extern void pythagoras_(float *a, float *b, float *c);
#endif

int
main(void)
{
    float c;
#if 0
    printf("Factorial of 7 is: %d\n", fact_(7));
#else
    int n = 7;
    printf("Factorial of 7 is: %d\n", fact_(&n));
#endif

#if 0
    pythagoras_(30, 40, &c);
#else
    float a = 30;
    float b = 40;
    pythagoras_(&a, &b, &c);
#endif
    printf("Hypotenuse if sides 30, 40 is: %f\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
    INTEGER*4 FUNCTION Fact (n)
    INTEGER*4 n
    INTEGER*4 i, amt
    amt = 1
    DO i = 1, n
        amt = amt * i
    END DO
    Fact = amt
    END

    SUBROUTINE Pythagoras (a, b, c)
    REAL*4 a
    REAL*4 b
    REAL*4 c
    c = SQRT (a * a + b * b)
    END
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
Factorial of 7 is: 5040
Hypotenuse if sides 30, 40 is: 50.000000
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I get the same `undefined reference` error from your code!

Aha!

One thing I didn't mention [because I didn't think it would make a difference] is that I changed the source file names to use all lowercase letters (e.g. `CMAIN.C --> cmain.c` and `FORSUBS.FOR --> forsubs.for`)

With that, the output of `nm *.o` produces:

```
 cmain.o:
                 U fact_
0000000000000000 T main
                 U printf
                 U pythagoras_

forsubs.o:
0000000000000000 T fact_
0000000000000045 T pythagoras_
```

The change in the fortran source filename doesn't matter too much. But, the C source filename does!

More to the point it's the filename *suffix* (i.e. `.C` changed to `.c`).

This is because `gcc` will [try to be smart and] look at the suffix to determine which language the file is written in and compile accordingly. For example, `gcc -c foo.cpp` will compile the file as if it is written in `c++` and *not* `c`, just as if the command were: `g++ -c foo.cpp`

Although `.cpp` is the [more] usual suffix for a `c++` filename, an alternate suffix for `c++` files is: `.C`

That is, most projects use the `.cpp` convention, but some use the `.C` convention. One of the reasons for preferring `.cpp` over `.C` is that Windows filesystems are case insensitive. So, `.C` and `.c` would appear the same. However, POSIX systems (e.g. linux, macOSX, iOS, android, etc.) have case sensitive filenames so either convention can be used.

So, `gcc -c CMAIN.C` will compile as `c++`. This does `c++` style "name mangling" of symbols--not what we want. In `c++`, the mangling is done to allow "overloading" of function names. That is, two [or more] different functions can have the same name, as long as they use different arguments. For example:

```
void calc(int val);
void calc(int val1,int val2);
void calc(double fval);
```

Here is the output of `nm *.o` if we use `CMAIN.C`:

```
 CMAIN.o:
0000000000000000 T main
                 U printf
                 U _Z11pythagoras_PfS_S_
                 U _Z5fact_Pi

FORSUBS.o:
0000000000000000 T fact_
0000000000000045 T pythagoras_
```

Running *that* file through `c++filt` to "demangle" the `c++` names we get:

```
 CMAIN.o:
0000000000000000 T main
                 U printf
                 U pythagoras_(float*, float*, float*)
                 U fact_(int*)

FORSUBS.o:
0000000000000000 T fact_
0000000000000045 T pythagoras_
```

So, try to use lowercase filenames if possible [that is recommended best practice]. But, at a minimum, don't use `.C`

Comment: I get the same `undefined reference` error from your code!

Comment: oh my! I would have never though that I could be beaten by a file extension! why gcc does that?!! If I wanted to compile as cpp I would have used g++!

Comment: @Foad That is not how GCC works. You can call `gcc` even on Fortran source codes. Or `gfortran` on C++ source files. The correct front end is NOT selected by the command you use.

Comment: @VladimirF: True, but, the command tells which libraries it tries to link with. So there's still good reasons to use the command matching the language of the source file.

Answer (score 4):

Fortran passes variables by reference, as mentioned in the first sentences of any Fortran to C tutorial. So you:

1. Cannot just remove the `[VALUE]`, you should add the modern VALUE attribute or change the C code to pass pointers.
2. Should not use pointers on the Fortran side of `[REFERENCE]`, but just remove it.
3. Use the actual name mangling for your compiler, these days normally `subroutine_name_` (appended underscore, name is lowercase) or use the modern `bind(C, name="binding_name")` attribute.

Without modern Fortran, but with `VALUE` (it is just a PITA without):

```
  INTEGER*4 FUNCTION Fact (n)
  INTEGER*4, VALUE :: n 
  INTEGER*4 i, amt
  amt = 1
  DO i = 1, n
    amt = amt * i
  END DO
  Fact = amt
  END

  SUBROUTINE Pythagoras (a, b, c) bind(C)
  REAL*4, VALUE :: a
  REAL*4, VALUE :: b
  REAL*4 c
  c = SQRT (a * a + b * b)
  END
```

and than just change your C names to lowercase (`pythagoras_`, `fact_`)... With the `VALUE` attribute you do not need to introduce all those C temporaries you see in the other answer. The `bind(C)` is required for `VALUE` to work properly. It will save you from rewriting the code that calls the Fortran procedures.

For best modern experience use `bind(C,name="any_name_you_want")` to set the exact linkage symbol name.

Comment: "change the C code to pass pointers" so should I put `7`, `40` and `30` in some variables and then pass the pointer?

Comment: See the edit. It takes time to code on a mobile phone.

Comment: @Vladimir, the Fortran does not specify how variables are passed.  It my be reference or by value or by chiseling on stone tablets.

Comment: @evets I know that very well and I know even many more details. However, one must distinguish the level of information and the level of correctness based on the target audience. Teachers always lie. Or well... make simplifications. Without this particular simplifications many C codes that call Fortran external subroutines (including very often used packages like BLAS or LAPACK) wouldn't work. Or the Fortran code would have to be updated which is explicitly what this question tries to avoid - it wants **minimal** changes.

Comment: @evets I know here often who writes more gets more upvotes, but to actually inform someone to get the job done less is often better. Even if that means omission of some details.

Comment: @VladimirF I appreciate your support. I will do more research about the `, VALUE ::` attribute. Thanks for your help.